# Ponctuation : point final requis à la fin des infinitives ?

Tags: ponctuation

La question est très simple ; faut-il, oui ou non, terminer les phrases infinitives par une ponctuation, en particulier un point final lorsque l'on passe à autre chose sur une nouvelle ligne ? Par exemple cette source semble affirmer le contraire, puisque la [prescription](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/point%20final/fr-fr/) se limite aux [phrases déclaratives](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/grammaire/la-phrase-declarative-171.php), ce qu'une [infinitive](http://www.alloprof.qc.ca/BV/Pages/f1145.aspx) n'est pas. Cependant la présente [source](http://piquredufrancais.ccdmd.qc.ca/netquiz/447/9_5.3-Web/main.html), comme la référence précédente d'ailleurs, montre qu'un point final est utilisé. Je n'ai pas pu extraire de LBU d'information spécifique à ce sujet et je ne trouve pas d'autres sources.
On doit considérer le cas des phrases infinitives sur les mises en garde au public par exemple car elles ne comportent jamais de ponctuation ;

- Ne pas fumer dans les couloirs
- Garder toutes les portes fermées

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toute phrase doit se terminer par une ponctuation.

[wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase#D%C3%A9limitation_de_la_phrase)

Voici un extrait du [« Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie nationale »](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_des_r%C3%A8gles_typographiques_en_usage_%C3%A0_l%27Imprimerie_nationale)

[image]

Comment: Vous m'aviez parlé un jour de la Bible de la ponctuation, dont je ne me rappelle pas, sauf que d'après ce que j'en ai appris après une vérification de votre lien, elle contient un grand nombre de règles (peut être 300) ; avez-vous toujours cette référence à portée ? Quelle serait l'avis que l'on y trouve à ce sujet ? La référence que vous donnez est très terse en explication ; je demande cela parce qu'il y plusieurs références qui stipulent bien « phrases déclaratives » et que dans mes années scolaires j'ai été exposé à la règle excluant les infinitives.

Comment: @LPH: La bible enquestion est [« Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie nationale»](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_des_r%C3%A8gles_typographiques_en_usage_%C3%A0_l%27Imprimerie_nationale). Je ne l'ai malheureusement pas sous la main.

Answer (score 5):

Une phrase doit impérativement être terminée par un point, qu'il soit final, abréviatif, d'exclamation, d'interrogation ou de suspension.

En revanche, les titres de livre, de chapitre, les devises et les slogans ne doivent pas être terminés pas un point final. Ils peuvent avoir d'autres ponctuations finales.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne sais pas si j'ai bien compris votre question. Il nous faut terminer chaque phrase correcte par un point de ponctuation, même les phrases infinitives.

Quelques exemples :

> Parler à voix basse ; frapper avant d'entrer ; travailler pour réussir.
>
> Ne pas se pencher au dehors.
>
> S'adresser au concierge.

Comment: Il faut éliminer de votre réponse tout ce qui est phrases déclarative parce que ces phrases ne relèvent pas de la question ; toute forme conjuguée et pour laquelle il y a un sujet résulte en une phrase déclarative. Il ne reste que les phrase du n°4.

Comment: Si ça vous convient, vous pouvez modifier ma réponse. À vrai dire j'étais en train de l'effacer:-)!